# UX Architecture leverage over development process

Tags: jobs, relations, management, product-management

How can a new UX Architect (newly created position) apply the best leverage to improve new and existing products across a medium-large organization?

This position is in a corporate IT department where UX practice is brand new, within a larger organization that is also very immature in it's UX approach.

As a UX Architect I would expect to be able to guide, and sometimes enforce good UX design decisions throughout the development process. Is this something that you have experienced in your organization?

How can a person with an architect-level role effectively guide, direct, educate and enforce UX standards across multiple development groups? What authorities are required, and what tools are available?

I'm currently thinking about integrated style-guides and pattern libraries to start with, along with best practice education sessions and offering design review and product usability testing services at the start of new cycles.

Answer (score 2):

Your ideas are all good ones, but you have quite a job ahead of you, unless you are very lucky and the organization KNOWS it needs UX and is ready and willing.

Your approach will need to be multi fold:

1. Find a project you can knock out of the park and do it
2. Use that as leverage to gain credibility as you do your education tour
3. Build relationships, networks cross-functionally across the org
4. Cultivate sponsors and champions in your leadership and on teams
5. Get everyone involved and excited about design - make them a part of it!
6. Communicate progress and successes widely

Mastercard SVP Karen Pascoe talks quite a bit about this sort of organizational transformation; her talk at EUX2016 was very good:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2Zio_HG0xA

Autodesk's Maria Giudice also talks a bit about this in her great talk:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qd9WTqEHXNE

Answer (score 0):

UX isn't a 1 man job. You will need to get everyone involved. I think your 1st task is to provide awareness and education about UX and its potential benefits to various stakeholders in the company.

since you have mentioned style guides and pattern libraries, you can show how these benefit various members in the organisation.

Once people see how ux can personally benefit them, then things get much more simple and there will be less roadblocks for you.